How to display the names of clients and average check of orders, the amount of which is from 1000 dollars (inclusive)?
I want to display the names of clients and average check of orders, the amount of which is from 1000 dollars (inclusive). The average order amount must be rounded up to two hundredths
So, I write the following SQL for the query:
SELECT
  Customers.CustomerName,
  ROUND(AVG(Orders.OrderTotal), 2) AS AverageCheck
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderTotal >= 1000
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerName;

But running it on the W3school SQL Tryit Editor shows the following result: Error in SQL: No value given for one or more required parameters.
When I try this query:
SELECT
  c.CustomerName, 
  ROUND(AVG(o.OrderTotal), 2) AS AverageOrderAmount
FROM Customers c
JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.OrderTotal >= 1000
GROUP BY c.CustomerName;

The w3school SQL Tryit Editor shows the following error: Error in SQL: Syntax error in FROM clause.
So what should the correct SQL be?

Both queries work for SQL-Server on dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/irJK-oCX

Yes. Also it works on everywhere but it doesn't work on the W3school SQL Editor.

On W3School the orders table does not have a OrderTotal column

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Sorry for that. I didn't notice that. Thanks for telling me.

On W3School the orders table does not have a OrderTotal column.
It only has
OrderID,    CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate,  ShipperID

I was trying this also. But after that I am not able to complete this. Though this query is running on the w3school.
SELECT c.customerName, COUNT(o.orderID) AS OrderNumber,
SUM(p.price) AS TotalPrice FROM Orders o, Customers c, orderdetails od, products p
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND od.productID = p.productID AND o.orderID = od.orderID
GROUP BY c.customerName;

@Tareq Khan Please clarify your comment. What did you try that did not work?

W3Schools has its own rules for using multiple joins. You must include all sources (FROM clause, JOIN) within brackets. Additionally, the Orders table does not have an OrderTotal column.
So the correct query should be:
SELECT c.customerName, ROUND(AVG(od.quantity * p.price), 2) AS averageOrderValue
FROM ((((Customers c)
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.customerID = o.customerID)
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.orderID = od.orderID)
INNER JOIN Products p ON od.productID = p.productID)
WHERE (od.quantity * p.price) >= 1000
GROUP BY c.customerName;


May be GROUP BY c.customerName having sum(od.quantity * p.price) >= 1000
